# How to add a UIActionSheet when selecting image from gallery via UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to add an "Are you sure" button when a person is selecting an image from their gallery by way of the UIImagePicker.  Here is how I am trying right now.

Here is how I present the UIImagePicker

```
{
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Once they have selected the image this method is called

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    myImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Do you want to set this image as your profile picture?"
                                                        delegate:self 
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"No" 
                                                        destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic;
    [actionSheet showInView:[self.view window]];
}
```

Then if the `destructiveButton` is selected I return to the view that I called UIImagePicker from.

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.destructiveButtonIndex) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Problem is I am throwing this exception

Assertion failure in -[UIActionSheet showInView:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/UIActionSheet.m:5123
2013-10-10 22:14:55.735 Globism[1997:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: view != nil'
*** First throw call stack:

My guess is that it has to do with `[actionSheet showInView:[self.view window]];` but I don't know how to get around it.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Snippets really help!  Thanks!

Comment: How do you presenting the **UIImagePicker** ..?

Comment: only write self.view or Are you using Tabbar in your application? If yes than write showFromTabbar

Comment: @KumarKl see my edit on how I present the imagePicker

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda I've tried self.view first... thanks for the tip on showFromTabbar I didn't even notice I was covering my tab bar until you mentioned it.  Still have the original problem.

Comment: Ok . Can't you use UIalertView instead of UIactionSheet . UIAlertView works fro sure ..

Comment: @KumarKl From what I understand UIAlertView is more of a warning dialog.  Pops up to let you know you have deleted something or that something has been updated.  UIActionView is specific for executing an action based upon what button is pushed... Correct me if I'm wrong here.